# Linear algebra - Vector space. Finding three different elements and adding and scalar-multiplying them

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V=\{[x,y]^T\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\geq 0,y\geq 0\}$.

Present at least three different elements of the set $V$. After adding and scalar-multiplying your three elements and examining the results, form an informed judgement as to whether $V$ forms a vector space.

I am very confused on how to begin this problem. First of all, I am totally confused on what question is asking. Based on the question, I thought the elements would be $(3,4)$, $(6,9)$ or $(1,2)$, but it turns out that is not correct according to the teacher. I would appreciate if someone would give me an example similar to my question, so that I can figure it out.

Comment: The elements you listed certainly seem to be elements of the space $V$, so I'm not sure why your teacher said that is incorrect. It is probably best to ask your teacher about it. As for the second part of the question, if you add together these elements or take scalar multiples of them, do you always get something else in $V$? (Hint: try a negative scalar multiple.)

Answer (score 1):

The question asks you to examine whether $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

There are infinite many triples with distinct elements of $V$. It is true that $(3,4)$, $(6,9)$ and $(1,2)$ are distinct elements of $V$. Now, regarding whether $V$ is a vector space or not, you need to check whether $av+bw\in V$ for all $v,w\in V$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. It is easy to see that $(x,y)\notin V$ if $x<0$ or $y<0$.

Suppose $a=-1, b=0$ and $v=(3,4)$, $w=(6,9)$. Then we have $av+bw=(-3,-4)$. Thus $av+bw\notin V$. Since $av+bw\notin V$ for some $v,w\in V$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, we can conclude that $V$ is not a vector space.

Comment: @ Supreeth could you please give me an example. I am unclear with the notations. Thanks